# How to increase python heap size on windows

Tags: python, memory-management, heap-memory

I'm using [ocropus](https://github.com/tmbdev/ocropy) library for large images.

When I try to process 5000x4000pix image, MemoryError is raised.

I looked up an answer, but [following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308091/how-to-limit-python-heap-size) is all that I found.

But, I am working on windows, and my servers are working on windows; therefore that solution does not work for me.

Is there an any parameters for Python,  like -Xmx in Java?

Thank you, for your answers.

Comment: I don't know about windows, but on linux python processes don't have a limit(unlike java). I used to do some pretty heavy processing and had processes grow to ~3~4GB heap size with not a single sign of trouble(except when the thing hits RAM size and the disks starts thrashing swapping things in and out, but that's expected)

Comment: Chances are, your problem is elsewhere, whatever processing you're doing with the image is causing you to run out of memory rather than the image itself.

Comment: It could be stack related. On Windows, `PyOS_CheckStack` is used in `PyEval_EvalFrameEx`, `PyObject_Repr`, `PyObject_Call`, etc. When it fails the caller raises a `MemoryError("stack overflow")`.