# Evaluate math equations from unsafe user input in Python

Tags: python, eval, sandbox

I have a website where the user enters math equations (expressions) and then those equations are evaluated against data (constants) provided by the website. The math operations needed include symbols, arithmetic operations, `min()`, `max()` and some other basic functions. A sample equation could be:

```
max(a * b + 100, a / b - 200)
```

One could simply `eval()` this using Python, but as we all know this leads compromising the site. What would be the safe approach of doing math equation evaluation?

If one chooses to use Python itself to evaluate the expression are there any Python sandboxes which would limit the Python, so that only user supplier operators and functions are available. Full-fledged Python, like defining functions, should be totally disabled. Subprocesses are ok (see [PyPy sandbox](http://pypy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/sandbox.html)). Specially, for loops and other holes for exploiting memory and CPU usage should be closed.

Comment: Have you tried googling "python safe eval"? This produces a number of highly relevant resources, including some on this site.

Comment: Naturally I have. In fact I have been working with RestrictedPython library in the past: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/RestrictedPython - I am looking little bit more insight what Google can give you

Comment: PyPy's sandboxed mode looks promising http://pypy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/sandbox.html

Comment: Also found this solution (which doesn't do symbols) http://stackoverflow.com/a/11952343/315168

Comment: Here is the answer - apparently moderators closed this question before the answered could have posted this and he contacted me privately: https://gist.github.com/miohtama/34a83d870a14aa7e580d

Comment: I think that code needs to come with a formal proof of safety and correctness. :-)

Comment: @NPE: check the answer below for the formal proof :)

Comment: possible dupe  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11951701/safe-way-to-parse-user-supplied-mathematical-formula-in-python

Comment: have you considered client-side Python: http://www.skulpt.org/ or Emscripten http://repl.it/languages/Python for your web-site?

Comment: related: simpler version [Evaluating a mathematical expression in a string](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2371436/4279)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: Very interesting technologies, though they are difficult to apply here.

Comment: Seriously this question, as is, was once closed as Off-Topic? (seems pretty on-topic to me and all who upvoted) Oh crap where is our world going to...

Comment: @LuisMasuelli: Welcome to StackOverflow!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a relatively easy of doing this in Python without third party packages.

- Using `compile()` to prepare a single-line Python expression to be bytecode for `eval()`
- Not running the bytecode through `eval()`, but instead run it in your custom opcode loop and only implement opcodes which you really need. E.g. no built-ins, no attribute access, so the sandbox cannot escaped.

However there are some gotchas, like preparing for CPU exhaustion and memory exhaustion, which are not specific to this method and are issue on other approaches too.

[Here is a full blog post about the topic](http://opensourcehacker.com/2014/10/29/safe-evaluation-of-math-expressions-in-pure-python/). [Here is a related gist](https://gist.github.com/miohtama/34a83d870a14aa7e580d). Below is shortened sample code.

```
""""

    The orignal author: Alexer / #python.fi

"""

import opcode
import dis
import sys
import multiprocessing
import time

# Python 3 required
assert sys.version_info[0] == 3, "No country for old snakes"


class UnknownSymbol(Exception):
    """ There was a function or constant in the expression we don't support. """


class BadValue(Exception):
    """ The user tried to input dangerously big value. """

    MAX_ALLOWED_VALUE = 2**63


class BadCompilingInput(Exception):
    """ The user tried to input something which might cause compiler to slow down. """


def disassemble(co):
    """ Loop through Python bytecode and match instructions  with our internal opcodes.

    :param co: Python code object
    """
    code = co.co_code
    n = len(code)
    i = 0
    extended_arg = 0
    result = []
    while i < n:
        op = code[i]

        curi = i
        i = i+1
        if op >= dis.HAVE_ARGUMENT:
            # Python 2
            # oparg = ord(code[i]) + ord(code[i+1])*256 + extended_arg
            oparg = code[i] + code[i+1] * 256 + extended_arg
            extended_arg = 0
            i = i+2
            if op == dis.EXTENDED_ARG:
                # Python 2
                #extended_arg = oparg*65536L
                extended_arg = oparg*65536
        else:
            oparg = None

        # print(opcode.opname[op])

        opv = globals()[opcode.opname[op].replace('+', '_')](co, curi, i, op, oparg)

        result.append(opv)

    return result

# For the opcodes see dis.py
# (Copy-paste)
# https://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html

class Opcode:
    """ Base class for out internal opcodes. """
    args = 0
    pops = 0
    pushes = 0
    def __init__(self, co, i, nexti, op, oparg):
        self.co = co
        self.i = i
        self.nexti = nexti
        self.op = op
        self.oparg = oparg

    def get_pops(self):
        return self.pops

    def get_pushes(self):
        return self.pushes

    def touch_value(self, stack, frame):
        assert self.pushes == 0
        for i in range(self.pops):
            stack.pop()


class OpcodeArg(Opcode):
    args = 1


class OpcodeConst(OpcodeArg):
    def get_arg(self):
        return self.co.co_consts[self.oparg]


class OpcodeName(OpcodeArg):
    def get_arg(self):
        return self.co.co_names[self.oparg]


class POP_TOP(Opcode):
    """Removes the top-of-stack (TOS) item."""
    pops = 1
    def touch_value(self, stack, frame):
        stack.pop()


class DUP_TOP(Opcode):
    """Duplicates the reference on top of the stack."""
    # XXX: +-1
    pops = 1
    pushes = 2
    def touch_value(self, stack, frame):
        stack[-1:] = 2 * stack[-1:]


class ROT_TWO(Opcode):
    """Swaps the two top-most stack items."""
    pops = 2
    pushes = 2
    def touch_value(self, stack, frame):
        stack[-2:] = stack[-2:][::-1]


class ROT_THREE(Opcode):
    """Lifts second and third stack item one position up, moves top down to position three."""
    pops = 3
    pushes = 3
    direct = True
    def touch_value(self, stack, frame):
        v3, v2, v1 = stack[-3:]
        stack[-3:] = [v1, v3, v2]


class ROT_FOUR(Opcode):
    """Lifts second, third and forth stack item one position up, moves top down to position four."""
    pops = 4
    pushes = 4
    direct = True
    def touch_value(self, stack, frame):
        v4, v3, v2, v1 = stack[-3:]
        stack[-3:] = [v1, v4, v3, v2]


class UNARY(Opcode):
    """Unary Operations take the top of the stack, apply the operation, and push the result back on the stack."""
    pops = 1
    pushes = 1


class UNARY_POSITIVE(UNARY):
    """Implements TOS = +TOS."""
    def touch_value(self, stack, frame):
        stack[-1] = +stack[-1]


class UNARY_NEGATIVE(UNARY):
    """Implements TOS = -TOS."""
    def touch_value(self, stack, frame):
        stack[-1] = -stack[-1]


class BINARY(Opcode):
    """Binary operations remove the top of the stack (TOS) and the second top-most stack item (TOS1) from the stack. They perform the operation, and put the result back on the stack."""
    pops = 2
    pushes = 1


class BINARY_POWER(BINARY):
    """Implements TOS = TOS1 ** TOS."""
    def touch_value(self, stack, frame):
        TOS1, TOS = stack[-2:]
        print(TOS1, TOS)
        if abs(TOS1) > BadValue.MAX_ALLOWED_VALUE or abs(TOS) > BadValue.MAX_ALLOWED_VALUE:
            raise BadValue("The value for exponent was too big")

        stack[-2:] = [TOS1 ** TOS]


class BINARY_MULTIPLY(BINARY):
    """Implements TOS = TOS1 * TOS."""
    def touch_value(self, stack, frame):
        TOS1, TOS = stack[-2:]
        stack[-2:] = [TOS1 * TOS]


class BINARY_DIVIDE(BINARY):
    """Implements TOS = TOS1 / TOS when from __future__ import division is not in effect."""
    def touch_value(self, stack, frame):
        TOS1, TOS = stack[-2:]
        stack[-2:] = [TOS1 / TOS]


class BINARY_MODULO(BINARY):
    """Implements TOS = TOS1 % TOS."""
    def touch_value(self, stack, frame):
        TOS1, TOS = stack[-2:]
        stack[-2:] = [TOS1 % TOS]


class BINARY_ADD(BINARY):
    """Implements TOS = TOS1 + TOS."""
    def touch_value(self, stack, frame):
        TOS1, TOS = stack[-2:]
        stack[-2:] = [TOS1 + TOS]


class BINARY_SUBTRACT(BINARY):
    """Implements TOS = TOS1 - TOS."""
    def touch_value(self, stack, frame):
        TOS1, TOS = stack[-2:]
        stack[-2:] = [TOS1 - TOS]


class BINARY_FLOOR_DIVIDE(BINARY):
    """Implements TOS = TOS1 // TOS."""
    def touch_value(self, stack, frame):
        TOS1, TOS = stack[-2:]
        stack[-2:] = [TOS1 // TOS]


class BINARY_TRUE_DIVIDE(BINARY):
    """Implements TOS = TOS1 / TOS when from __future__ import division is in effect."""
    def touch_value(self, stack, frame):
        TOS1, TOS = stack[-2:]
        stack[-2:] = [TOS1 / TOS]


class BINARY_LSHIFT(BINARY):
    """Implements TOS = TOS1 << TOS."""
    def touch_value(self, stack, frame):
        TOS1, TOS = stack[-2:]
        stack[-2:] = [TOS1 << TOS]


class BINARY_RSHIFT(BINARY):
    """Implements TOS = TOS1 >> TOS."""
    def touch_value(self, stack, frame):
        TOS1, TOS = stack[-2:]
        stack[-2:] = [TOS1 >> TOS]


class BINARY_AND(BINARY):
    """Implements TOS = TOS1 & TOS."""
    def touch_value(self, stack, frame):
        TOS1, TOS = stack[-2:]
        stack[-2:] = [TOS1 & TOS]


class BINARY_XOR(BINARY):
    """Implements TOS = TOS1 ^ TOS."""
    def touch_value(self, stack, frame):
        TOS1, TOS = stack[-2:]
        stack[-2:] = [TOS1 ^ TOS]


class BINARY_OR(BINARY):
    """Implements TOS = TOS1 | TOS."""
    def touch_value(self, stack, frame):
        TOS1, TOS = stack[-2:]
        stack[-2:] = [TOS1 | TOS]


class RETURN_VALUE(Opcode):
    """Returns with TOS to the caller of the function."""
    pops = 1
    final = True
    def touch_value(self, stack, frame):
        value = stack.pop()
        return value


class LOAD_CONST(OpcodeConst):
    """Pushes co_consts[consti] onto the stack.""" # consti
    pushes = 1
    def touch_value(self, stack, frame):
        # XXX moo: Validate type
        value = self.get_arg()
        assert isinstance(value, (int, float))
        stack.append(value)


class LOAD_NAME(OpcodeName):
    """Pushes the value associated with co_names[namei] onto the stack.""" # namei
    pushes = 1
    def touch_value(self, stack, frame):
        # XXX moo: Get name from dict of valid variables/functions
        name = self.get_arg()
        if name not in frame:
            raise UnknownSymbol("Does not know symbol {}".format(name))
        stack.append(frame[name])


class CALL_FUNCTION(OpcodeArg):
    """Calls a function. The low byte of argc indicates the number of positional parameters, the high byte the number of keyword parameters. On the stack, the opcode finds the keyword parameters first. For each keyword argument, the value is on top of the key. Below the keyword parameters, the positional parameters are on the stack, with the right-most parameter on top. Below the parameters, the function object to call is on the stack. Pops all function arguments, and the function itself off the stack, and pushes the return value.""" # argc
    pops = None
    pushes = 1

    def get_pops(self):
        args = self.oparg & 0xff
        kwargs = (self.oparg >> 8) & 0xff
        return 1 + args + 2 * kwargs

    def touch_value(self, stack, frame):
        argc = self.oparg & 0xff
        kwargc = (self.oparg >> 8) & 0xff
        assert kwargc == 0
        if argc > 0:
            args = stack[-argc:]
            stack[:] = stack[:-argc]
        else:
            args = []
        func = stack.pop()

        assert func in frame.values(), "Uh-oh somebody injected bad function. This does not happen."

        result = func(*args)
        stack.append(result)


def check_for_pow(expr):
    """ Python evaluates power operator during the compile time if its on constants.

    You can do CPU / memory burning attack with ``2**999999999999999999999**9999999999999``.
    We mainly care about memory now, as we catch timeoutting in any case.

    We just disable pow and do not care about it.
    """
    if "**" in expr:
        raise BadCompilingInput("Power operation is not allowed")


def _safe_eval(expr, functions_and_constants={}, check_compiling_input=True):
    """ Evaluate a Pythonic math expression and return the output as a string.

    The expr is limited to 1024 characters / 1024 operations
    to prevent CPU burning or memory stealing.

    :param functions_and_constants: Supplied "built-in" data for evaluation
    """

    # Some safety checks
    assert len(expr) < 1024

    # Check for potential bad compiler input
    if check_compiling_input:
        check_for_pow(expr)

    # Compile Python source code to Python code for eval()
    code = compile(expr, '', 'eval')

    # Dissect bytecode back to Python opcodes
    ops = disassemble(code)
    assert len(ops) < 1024

    stack = []
    for op in ops:
        value = op.touch_value(stack, functions_and_constants)

    return value
```

Answer (score 9):

Disclaimer: I'm the Alexer mentioned in the code in the other answer. To be honest, I kind of suggested the bytecode parsing approach only half-jokingly, since I happened to have 99% of the code lying around for an unrelated project and so could whip together a POC in like a couple of minutes. That said, there shouldn't be anything wrong with it, per se; it's just that it's a more complex machinery that is needed for this task. In fact, you *should* be able to get away with just disassembling the code [checking the opcodes against a whitelist], checking that the constants and names are valid, and executing it with plain, evil eval after that. You should just lose the ability to insert paranoid extra checks all over the execution. (Another disclaimer: I still wouldn't feel comfortable enough to do it with eval)

Anyway, I had a boring moment, so I wrote some code to do this the smart way; using the AST instead of the bytecode. It's just an extra flag to `compile()`. (Or just `ast.parse()`, since you'll want the types from the module anyway)

```
import ast
import operator

_operations = {
        ast.Add: operator.add,
        ast.Sub: operator.sub,
        ast.Mult: operator.mul,
        ast.Div: operator.div,
        ast.Pow: operator.pow,
}

def _safe_eval(node, variables, functions):
        if isinstance(node, ast.Num):
                return node.n
        elif isinstance(node, ast.Name):
                return variables[node.id] # KeyError -> Unsafe variable
        elif isinstance(node, ast.BinOp):
                op = _operations[node.op.__class__] # KeyError -> Unsafe operation
                left = _safe_eval(node.left, variables, functions)
                right = _safe_eval(node.right, variables, functions)
                if isinstance(node.op, ast.Pow):
                        assert right < 100
                return op(left, right)
        elif isinstance(node, ast.Call):
                assert not node.keywords and not node.starargs and not node.kwargs
                assert isinstance(node.func, ast.Name), 'Unsafe function derivation'
                func = functions[node.func.id] # KeyError -> Unsafe function
                args = [_safe_eval(arg, variables, functions) for arg in node.args]
                return func(*args)

        assert False, 'Unsafe operation'

def safe_eval(expr, variables={}, functions={}):
        node = ast.parse(expr, '<string>', 'eval').body
        return _safe_eval(node, variables, functions)

if __name__ == '__main__':
        import math

        print safe_eval('sin(a*pi/b)', dict(a=1, b=2, pi=math.pi), dict(sin=math.sin))
```

The same thing applies to this as to the bytecode version; if you check the operations against a whitelist and check that the names and values are valid, you should be able to get away with calling eval on the AST. (But again, I still wouldn't do it. Because paranoid. And paranoia is good when eval is concerned)

Comment: Do I need to update this to {ast.Div: operator.truediv, ast.FloorDiv: operator.floordiv,} for Python 3?

Comment: numpy.safe_eval is a wrapper around the builtin ast.literal_eval (https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval ). Is that similar to your answer?

Comment: Apparently not. According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/20748308, ast.literal_eval allows addition but bans multiplication. "Kind of like a backwards repr for simple built-in types. Actual expression evaluation is not included, and the fact that this works with Python 3 is just a nice-to-have side effect from its implementation."

Comment: @jimbo1qaz: Yeah, adding `{ast.Div: operator.truediv, ast.FloorDiv: operator.floordiv}` should be the only change needed for Python 3. As you already noticed, `ast.literal_eval()` is exactly what it says on the tin: It evaluates literal values, that is, numbers, strings, tuples, lists, dictionaries, and the like. So it's not meant for evaluating math operations, which is what the question asked. I think even the support for addition is just there so that it supports complex literals, eg. `(2+3j)`.

Comment: It cannot be overstated how important it is to validate in the input variables on this. Python encourages duck-typing: Many builtin Python objects override +, /, -, *, and  your own application's objects might override them too. 

That said: I don't see anything wrong with this solution so long as you validate that you're only working with Python numbers.

Comment: Whoops, there actually is one remaining problem with Aleksi's solution: A denial of service vector by way of CPU or memory exhaustion. Imagine we safe_eval a string like `99**99**99**99`. Python will keep computing a larger and larger integer forever. The CPU exhaustion vector could be addressed with a timeout. Memory exhaustion is trickier. Spinning off a child process and limiting its heap size seems like a reasonable place to start: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308091/how-to-limit-the-heap-size

Comment: @AdamEasterling: If you look more closely, the code actually checks that the exponent for power operations stays less than 100, as an example as to how you might prevent such denial of service attacks, and just replacing with 99 won't work either, because of the order of operations for exponentiation. But you're still, of course, correct: Even though it grows a lot slower, with proper parenthesization, it's possible to make the left argument grow fast enough for denial of service. A proper protection would limit the actual result length by checking eg. `len(str(left)) * right < 1000` instead.

Comment: Ah yes, you're right about order of operations. My suggestion that `99**99**99**99` would break your solution is not correct, since first it would calculate the _last_ `99**99` pair, then try `99**` against that, which would fail due to the check of the right side of the POW operation. (One small note: The assert should probably be a raise exception instead. If Python is started with the -O argument, asserts are stripped out. Usually it is recommended to raise exceptions when validating user input.)

Comment: And yes, as you said, `((99**99)**99)**99` would still cause CPU exhaustion as the solution is presently written. Adding in a check to the left side of the POW operation would help with this. However, I wonder if there are still problems: Let's say we just disallowed POW entirely. Is it possible to make a DOS attack using any of the remaining operations? What extra validation could we add that would eliminate these problems? (One idea would be to add a large number check to every op. All the DOS problems I can think of involve computing very large numbers.)