# How can I evaluate math expressions with human readable units in python?

Tags: python, expression, evaluation, units-of-measurement

Is there a way to evaluate expressions from strings that include human readable number units?

For example:

```
myformula='1u+1e-6'
result = eval(myformula)
```

... should be equivalent to `1e-6+1e-6` (where u=micro).

Comment: how is `1u` more readable than `1e-6` ... which humans are you refering too ?

Comment: Probably a nice learning exercise to create this kind of parser on your own. (surely not required in real life!)

Comment: @JoranBeasley: From the choice of notation, it sounds that would be scientists and engineers - who, are very much human as are we. ;)

Comment: and they dont understand `1e-6`?  or that is somehow more confusing than `1u`?

Comment: @JoranBeasley: yes, of course they do - I'm not arguing that. To me, it's clear that it's lazier and easier to write something in a familiar notation, as opposed to having to type more. And, in the context of programming about being productively lazy, to me his need for that makes sense.

Comment: speaking as a scientist, I would never just give a 'micro' or 'nano' or whatever unless the units were attached - 'microliter', 'kilogram', etc. I've never seen anyone just using the prefix...

Comment: Why 1u and and not 1µ? :)

Comment: well, it's preference of use for certain tools, in this case here I'm talking about SPICE circuit simulation, in that world people just prefer to use the symbolic expressions rather than scientific

Answer (score 6):

This answer expands somewhat on Joran's to replace all [SI affices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_prefix) with the appropriate exponents:

```
import re

SI = {
    "T": 12,
    "G": 9,
    "M": 6,
    "k": 3,
    "h": 2,
    "da": 1,
    "d": -1,
    "c": -2,
    "m": -3,
    "u": -6,
    "n": -9,
    "p": -12,
}

SI_REGEX = re.compile(r"(?<=\d)(%s)\b" % "|".join(SI))

def repl_si(match):
    return "e%d" % SI[match.group()]

def defix(formula):
    return re.sub(SI_REGEX, repl_si, formula)
```

Using the dictionary `SI`, we create a regular expression that will match any of the keys in `SI` as long as they're [preceded](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) by a digit and followed by a word boundary:

```
(?<=\d)(T|G|M|k|h|da|d|c|m|u|n|p)\b
```

Next, we define a [substitution function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) `repl_si()` that looks up the match in `SI` and replaces it with `"e"` concatenated with the exponent.

Then, all we have to do is write a function that calls `re.sub()` appropriately with the regex, substitution function and formula, and *voilà*:

```
>>> defix("1T + 2G + 3M + 4k + 5h + 6da + 7d + 8c + 9m + 1u + 2n + 3p")
'1e12 + 2e9 + 3e6 + 4e3 + 5e2 + 6e1 + 7e-1 + 8e-2 + 9e-3 + 1e-6 + 2e-9 + 3e-12'
```

Now all you need to do is call `eval()` on the result, which of course you should [absolutely never do](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html) with user-supplied input.

Comment: thanks, how can I force conversion only if the unit trails a number directly [0-9], I feel that the difference can be in the SI_REGEX expression

Comment: Here's a safe approach to processing user input math expressions in python. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26505420/evaluate-math-equations-from-unsafe-user-input-in-python

Comment: @sam.freeman: Yes, that is possible, using a lookbehind assertion in the regular expression. Something like this should work: `SI_REGEX = re.compile(r"(?<=\d)(%s)" % "|".join(SI))`

Comment: @sam.freeman I've incorporated Håken's suggestion so that substitutions are only made when the affix is preceded by a digit.

Comment: You can also use a word boundary `\b` after the  to make the expression even stricter. Then it will work with a regular dictionary as well. `r"(?<=\d)(%s)\b" % "|".join(SI)`

Comment: @HåkenLid Hahaha yes, good point. Edited; thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

```
myformula='1u+1e-6'
result = eval(re.sub("(\d+)u","\\1e-6",myformula))
```

should work... by just replacing any digits followed immediatly by u with e-6 before evaluating

Comment: why -1? I feel this answers OP question ... if it doesnt please explain why not

Answer (score 0):

Adding an answer, mostly inspired by Joran, it probably isn't as elegant as Zero's but I think it does the job
one thing I made sure that the unit MUST be preceded by a numeric figure (\d+)

I fixed the units by processing a series of substitutes over different units

```
myformula = '1E+3P+0.5T-7G-6M+2.5k-1m+3.7u+4n+13p-59f-73a+0.5e-5'
tmp_exp = re.sub('(\d+)E', r'\1e18', myformula)
tmp_exp = re.sub('(\d+)P', r'\1e15', tmp_exp)
tmp_exp = re.sub('(\d+)T', r'\1e12', tmp_exp)
tmp_exp = re.sub('(\d+)G', r'\1e9', tmp_exp)
tmp_exp = re.sub('(\d+)M', r'\1e6', tmp_exp)
tmp_exp = re.sub('(\d+)k', r'\1e3', tmp_exp)
tmp_exp = re.sub('(\d+)m', r'\1e-3', tmp_exp)
tmp_exp = re.sub('(\d+)u', r'\1e-6', tmp_exp)
tmp_exp = re.sub('(\d+)n', r'\1e-9', tmp_exp)
tmp_exp = re.sub('(\d+)p', r'\1e-12', tmp_exp)
tmp_exp = re.sub('(\d+)f', r'\1e-15', tmp_exp)
tmp_exp = re.sub('(\d+)a', r'\1e-18', tmp_exp)
```

tmp_exp will come out as
1e18+3e15+0.5e12-7e9-6e6+2.5e3-1e-3+3.7e-6+4e-9+13e-12-59e-15-73e-18+0.5e-5

Comment: The main difference between your solution and mine is that it has to process the formula multiple times, rather than just once. Unless performance is an issue, that's not a problem, but yes, it does feel somewhat inelegant to write nearly the same line of code a dozen times. There's nothing to stop you iterating over a dict instead, though ...