# Total allocation exceeds 95.00% (960,285,889 bytes) of heap memory- pyspark error

Tags: python, csv, pyspark, heap-memory, parquet

I wrote a script in python 2.7 that using pyspark for converting csv to parquet and other stuff.
when I ran my script on a small data it works well but when I did it on a bigger data (250GB) I crush on the following error- Total allocation exceeds 95.00% (960,285,889 bytes) of heap memory.
How can I solve this problem? and what is the reason that it's happening?
tnx!

part of code:
libraries imported:
    `import pyspark as ps
    from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, IntegerType, 
    DoubleType, StringType, TimestampType,LongType,FloatType
    from collections import OrderedDict
    from sys import argv`

using pyspark:

```
 schema_table_name="schema_"+str(get_table_name())
 print (schema_table_name)
 schema_file= OrderedDict()

schema_list=[]
ddl_to_schema(data)
for i in schema_file:
schema_list.append(StructField(i,schema_file[i]()))

schema=StructType(schema_list)
print schema

spark = ps.sql.SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
df = spark.read.option("delimiter", 
",").format("csv").schema(schema).option("header", "false").load(argv[2])
df.write.parquet(argv[3])

# df.limit(1500).write.jdbc(url = url, table = get_table_name(), mode = 
  "append", properties = properties)
# df = spark.read.jdbc(url = url, table = get_table_name(), properties = 
  properties)
pq = spark.read.parquet(argv[3])
pq.show()
```

just to clarify the schema_table_name is meant to save all tables name ( that are in DDL that fit the csv).

function ddl_to_schema just take a regular ddl and edit it to a ddl that parquet can work with.

Comment: Show us some code...

Comment: Add code to question, not in comments

Comment: @Lorelorelore tnx!

Comment: It looks like your only solution is to not read that entire file into memory.

Comment: @usr2564301 are you sure? there is no option to increase memory? if not, how to read part by part?

Comment: I can't send you extra memory per email or something. It really looks like you are simply Out of Memory. Nothing you can do about that – unless you mean "walk over to the nearest Best Buy and purchase a few additional GB chips.

Comment: @usr2564301 I meant that maybe it's a flag that I should increase the number that is defined there... because I saw a command like "set.memory.driver" but I couldn't really figure it out
tnx for replying!

Comment: anyone? please!

Answer (score 5):

It seems your driver is running out of memory.

By default the driver memory is set to 1GB. Since your program used 95% of it the application ran out of memory.

you can try to change it until you reach the "sweet spot" for your needs below I'm setting it to 2GB:

**pyspark --driver-memory 2g**

you can play with the executor memory too, although it doesn't seem to be the problem here (the default value for the executor is 4GB).

**pyspark --driver-memory 2g --executor-memory 8g**

the theory is, spark actions can offload data to the driver causing it to run out of memory if not properly sized. I can't tell for sure in your case, but it seems that the write is what is causing this.

You can take a look at the theory here (read about driver program and then check the actions):

https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/rdd-programming-guide.html#actions

Comment: Tnx for your help! I wanted to ask where should I type the command pyspark --driver-memory 2g ? in my script inside python? in Linux terminal?

Comment: If you are using spark 2.x I believe you can use:

./bin/spark-submit mypythonfile.py --driver-memory 2g

Comment: i did that and make sure that driver memory is now 2gb (i print it to the console) but i still get the same error with the same number.

Comment: Have you tried changing the executor memory as well (on 2.4 it defaults to 1G)?

Comment: @Pythonist did your issue got resolved after changing executor memory? If not can you suggest what else you tried?

Comment: Minimal side note: one can also export the variable previously to launching the program. `export PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS="--driver-memory 2g --executor-memory 8g"` In case one is not launching a direct spark app but rather something that uses spark internally

Answer (score 1):

If you are running a local script and aren't using `spark-submit` directly, you can do this:

```
import os

os.environ["PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS"] = "--driver-memory 2g"
```